# custom django comment form

Tags: django, django-comments

I use the default comment form in django as the document.But the tages like "name","url" aren`t suit my need.I need them become chinese.How can I change these tages and How to custom form with the comment framework?Please help me.Thanks a lot.
[image: The comment page of my blog]

And I custom the form but it doesn't work.

```
form.py:
class CommentFormmodels(CommentForm):
    name          = forms.CharField(label=("姓名"), max_length=50)
    email         = forms.EmailField(label=("Email address"))
    url           = forms.URLField(label=("个人站点")`enter code here`, required=False)
    comment       = forms.CharField(label=('评论'), widget=forms.Textarea,
        max_length=COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH)
    def get_comment_model(self):
        return CommentForm
    def get_comment_create_data(self):
        data = super(CommentFormmodels,self).get_comment_create_data()
        data['name']=self.cleaned_data['name']
        data['email'] = self.cleaned_data['email']
        data['url'] = self.cleaned_data['url']
        data['comment'] = self.cleaned_data['comment']
        return data
__init__.py:
from comment.forms import CommentFormmodels 

def get_fom():
    return CommentFormmodels
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/comments/custom/

You need to create your comments app, create new form from CommentForm and change labels in it.

Comment: Could I just change the label in my form and just create a form without models.py in my app?

Comment: Yes, just create form and add get_form function in __init__.py

Comment: Thanks a lot with your help,but I had already custom the comment from but it doesn`t work.I don`t konw what is going wrong!(I had change me queation already,please help me.Thanks)

Comment: Did you complete this step: `INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'my_comment_app',
    ...
]

COMMENTS_APP = 'my_comment_app'` ?

Comment: `def get_fom():` should be `def get_form():`

Comment: It`s exactly what I need.I really appreciate you help

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the labels section:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#label